# Synchronise MPI shared file pointers

Tags: mpi, mpi-io

Is there a standard way to synchronise MPI shared file pointers so that `MPI_File_get_position_shared` returns the same value on all processes?

For example the following program:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Initialize the MPI environment
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    MPI_File fh;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "foo", MPI_MODE_RDWR | MPI_MODE_CREATE, MPI_INFO_NULL, &fh);

    char* buf;
    buf = "hello";
    MPI_Status status;
    sleep(rank);
    MPI_File_write_shared(fh, buf, strlen(buf), MPI_CHAR, &status);    

    MPI_File_sync(fh); 

    MPI_Offset offset;
    MPI_File_get_position_shared(fh, &offset);

    printf("rank: %i, offset: %i\n", rank, (int) offset);

    MPI_File_close(&fh);

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

will print

```
rank: 0, offset: 5
rank: 1, offset: 10
rank: 2, offset: 15
rank: 3, offset: 20
```

It does work if I replace `MPI_File_sync(fh)` with `MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD)`: is that guaranteed to work correctly?

Comment: Which MPI library (vendor and version) are you using?

Comment: This was with MPICH, but I would like something cross-platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below function to synchronise the shared file pointer.

```
MPI_File_seek_shared( fh, OFFSET, MPI_SEEK_SET );
```

Syntax:

```
int MPI_File_seek_shared(
  MPI_File mpi_fh,
  MPI_Offset offset,
  int whence
);
```

`MPI_FILE_SEEK_SHARED` updates the shared file pointer according to `whence`, which has the following possible values:

`MPI_SEEK_SET`: the pointer is set to `offset`

`MPI_SEEK_CUR`: the pointer is set to the current pointer position plus `offset`

`MPI_SEEK_END`: the pointer is set to the end of file plus `offset`

[Reference](https://mpi.deino.net/mpi_functions/MPI_File_seek_shared.html)

Comment: I am afraid that does not answer the question that was "should the shared offsets be already synchronized?"

Comment: OK, thanks. I believe I misinterpreted the question.